# Laravel Migrate char() value as Foreign Key

Tags: laravel-4, migrate

I'm using UUID or GUIDs as a way of identifying certain records like users etc. I want to be able to link certain entity records to a user by adding a foreign key constraint to the user's unique ID.

Migrate doesn't seem to like adding the foreign key for some reason.

Any suggestions?

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Both values are of CHAR(36)

```
class CreateForeignKeys extends Migration {

/**
    * Run the migrations.
    */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('comments', function($table)
        {
            $table->foreign('author_id')->references('uuid')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('comments', function($table)
        {
            $table->dropForeign('comments_author_id_foreign');
        });
    }
```

}

This is something I just wrote as I'm in work. The only difference is that the copy at home has additional foreign key creations for separate tables, however they have their own:

```
Schema::table('table_name', function($table)
        {
            //
        });
```

The only thing I can think of is there may be multiple foreign key creations in the same Schema builder (Above). However, the foreign keys still relate to the same table.

The `uuid` column in the `users` table is a char(36)
The `author_id` column in the `comments` table is a char(36)

I've checked multiple times to ensure this is the case.

Comment: Please post your migration file.

Comment: Added the migration file with a bit of explaination of what else it contains. I've ensured that both columns are of the same value and length in the database.

Comment: We also need to see your `users` migration code.

Comment: The `users` table is already set. There isn't anything being changed in the `users` table with this migration.

Answer (score 0):

If there is already data in your `comments` table, then this error will be thrown when the `author_id` field is violating the foreign_key constraint. This can happen because of values that are not in `users.uuid` column or because of `NULL` values that are already in your table.

Comment: Both tables have 0 rows. Already encountered this error previously and had to sort it by clearing them.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem as if foreign key constraints are only supported for column datatypes of:

```
INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY UNIQUE
```

When working with Laravel's Migrate. This is because by standard, you're expected to be using

```
$table->increments('id');
```

As your only primary key, therefore should be the only thing you need to map column values to records of another table. This is fine, it's just an unnecessary restraint.

From what I've found looking around, the only way to add custom restraints/relationships is within your Eloquent Model classes. See [Eloquent Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships).

If anyone finds a better solution to this, I'd love to know, but for now I guess this will do.